# unfortunately myapplication has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a simple calculator app which has 2 edittextsand 1 TextViews:the problem is coming from string to double conversion.i dont know whats happening. the app DOESN`T OPEN and says "unfortunately has stoped".

here is my java code:

```
package com.example.aravind.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import static java.lang.Double.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    public double a,b,c;

    EditText e1, e2;
    public TextView e3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button add, sub, mul, div;

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        sub.setOnClickListener(this);
        mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mul.setOnClickListener(this);
        div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        div.setOnClickListener(this);
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
       a=Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
       b =Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button:
                // do your code
                c=a+b;

                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                // do your code
                c=a-b;
                break;

            case R.id.button3:
                // do your code
                c=a*b;
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                // do your code
                c=a/b;


        }
        String s= String.valueOf(c);
        e3.setText(s);


    }


}
```

and my xml code is

```
`
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aravind.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="num 1"
        android:autoText="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="num 2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="subtract"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="multiply"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="divide"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Result"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post crash log.

Comment: move `a=Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());` and `b=..` inside `onClick`

Comment: Put your error log

Comment: thanks for answering...iam not getting any errors...

Comment: it is working....

Answer (score 0):

Move the below piece of code inside onClick method (underneath every case)

```
a=Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
b =Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Te problem is that you are converting the strings to double in onCreate method. When there is nothing in those edit texts. Yo have to get that text and convert it to double when you click de operation button.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    public double a,b,c;

```
EditText e1, e2;
public TextView e3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button add, sub, mul, div;

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sub.setOnClickListener(this);
    mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mul.setOnClickListener(this);
    div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    div.setOnClickListener(this);
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    e3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    a=Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
    b =Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button:
            // do your code
            c=a+b;

            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            // do your code
            c=a-b;
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            // do your code
            c=a*b;
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            // do your code
            c=a/b;


    }
    String s= String.valueOf(c);
    e3.setText(s);


}
```

Comment: thank you very much....i understood the problem.is there any way that we can give a default value to edittexts....

Comment: You can specify the text in xml. With text attribute. But if you mean a default value for when there is no text. I think you have to do it programmatically like: 
`private Double getValue(Edittext edittext) {
if (editext.getText().toString().isEmpty) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return Double.parseDouble(edittext.getText().toString());
}
}`